# Dynamic Rest based input to Power BI Report

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Is it possible for a Power BI report to accept inputs like a Rest API and then load the data from SQL Server based on the input parameters ?
so that I can embed this in my React Web App, which is customer facing

I am aware that Power BI can apply a filter on the imported data but in this, it should always get the latest data from SQL Server based on POST inputs given.

> What i have done

I have created a Power BI report , but didn't find a way to call like Rest API and pass in dynamic parameters which i can inturn use in filtering data in report

> Data doesn't update until i reload and publish

Data in published report remains stale and not up to date with the database , until i reload the data from Power BI desktop and publish it

Comment: Read about Direct Query in Power BI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about And Power BI Embedding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-analytics-power-bi

Comment: Sure @DavidBrowne-Microsoft will go through these